# Group Likert scale responses in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a likert scale, (1-7), I want to group responses 2 to 7 together and leave out response 1. I'm using SPSS and getting a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you wanted to convert a variable. Lets call a variable "var1", and it needs to be converted to a dummy variable (0 and 1). In this case, your original variable can be transformed to "var1r" by using the following code.

RECODE var1 (1=0) (2=1) (3=1) (4=1) (5=1) (6=1) (7=1) into var1r .

The previous codes, creates a new variable, in which higher responses (2-7) are denoted by 1, and lower numbers (1) are denoted by 0. If you cross this variables in a cross tab, by using the next syntax:

cross var1 by var1r .

It would show your different values correspondingly. The latter is a way to verify you have recode your variables correctly. You can use the similar syntax and change variables at will.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for using syntax but I can't agree with `(1=0)` as it doesn't "leave out" value 1 at all! Also, by recoding into a new variable, you'll lost all value labels and the variable label and the order of the variables. If you want to learn something cool, check out the clone variables tool I linked to. You'll love it.

Comment: check out the comments below. Your syntax can be shortened a lot by using `(2 thru 7 = 2)` or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to [clone](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/clone-variables/) the original variable and then `RECODE` it into the same variable. The advantages are that you'll keep your variables in the same order and you already have the variable label and value labels. So if the variable name is v1, clone it and run

`RECODE v1 (7=2).`

Now adjust the value labels with

`ADD VALUE LABELS v1 2 "this value means ... or ...".`

Here you give the meaning of values 2 and 7. For "leaving out" value `1`, specify it as a [missing value](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/missing-values/) like so

`MISSING VALUES v1 (1).`

This presumes `1` is the only missing value. Now check all this by running

`CROSSTABS v1 by copy_v1.`

presuming your clone is called `copy_v1`. Following these steps is a short and safe road to a perfect result.

**UPDATE**

I think this syntax -although valid- may not be what the OP meant. Also, see comments below.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant `RECODE v1 (7=2).` Probably something more like `RECODE v1 (1 =1)(2 THRU 7 =2).` Also if there were value labels for all 6 values of 2 through 7 it would be easier to just make a new set of labels with just `VALUE LABELS`. Just using `ADD VALUE LABELS` would probably leave a set of irrelevant integer values. So in short, I don't see how transfering the original meta data is any easier then making a new set of meta-date for the transformed variable here.

Comment: @AndyW: on reading the OP again (was it modified?), I think you may be right on this. Note that `(1=1)` is only needed for `RECODE ... INTO ...` so it's redundant in your syntax. Assuming you're right, the OP had better use `VALUE LABELS` instead of `ADD VALUE LABELS` as explained [here](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/changing-variable-properties-5-variable-and-value-labels/#vallabs). Still, the order of variables and the variable label may be arguments for cloning and recoding into same variables.

Answer (score 0):

For recoding 1 into 0 and all other values into 1, an alternative is

`compute v1 = v1 gt 1.`

This looks like invalid syntax but it's explained in this [tutorial](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/compute-a-is-b-is-c/). You can use this trick for a lot of other stuff too.

For staying on the safe side, first clone the original variable so you can cross it with the recoded version to ensure that the result is correct.